# Tuple addition in pointfree

Tags: code-golf, tips, functional-programming, haskell

What is the shortest way we can express the function

```
f(a,b)(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)
```

in point-free notation?

[pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) gives us

```
uncurry (flip flip snd . (ap .) . flip flip fst . ((.) .) . (. (+)) . flip . (((.) . (,)) .) . (+))
```

which with a little bit of work can be shortened to

```
uncurry$(`flip`snd).((<*>).).(`flip`fst).((.).).(.(+)).flip.(((.).(,)).).(+)
```

for 76 bytes.  But this still seems *really* long and complex for such a simple task.  Is there any way we can express pairwise addition as a shorter point-free function?

To be clear by what I mean by point-free,  a point-free declaration of a function involves taking existing functions and operators and applying them to each other in such a way that the desired function is created.  Backticks, parentheses and literal values (`[]`,`0`,`[1..3]`, etc.) are allowed but keywords like `where` and `let` are not.  This means:

- You may not assign any variables/functions
- You may not use lambdas
- You may not import

[Here is the same question when it was a CMC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41972114#41972114)

Comment: I never understood why it is called “point-**free**” when it is actually *full* of points. :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder ["A common misconception is that the 'points' of pointfree style are the (.)
operator (function composition, as an ASCII symbol), which uses the same identifier as the decimal point. This is wrong. The term originated in topology, a branch of mathematics which works with spaces composed of points, and functions between those spaces. So a 'points-free' definition of a function is one which does not explicitly mention the points (values) of the space on which the function acts."](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree)

Comment: What's considered an external library? Are imports from [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) allowed?

Comment: I think so. So no keywords are allowed at all? I'd suggest explicitly allowing literal values like  0 and the empty tuple. Also, your example uses backticks, it should be clear then that's allowed.

Comment: @xnor Literals are allowed, keywords are not.  Thanks for asking for clarifications, hopefully everything is clear.

Comment: It's a shame we're not allowed to import [the best Haskell package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/plumbers-0.0.3/docs/Control-Plumbers.html), or else the solution would just be `(+)***(+)`.

Comment: An idea: `(+)<$>([1],2)<*>([3],4)` gives `([1,3],6)`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Please add this to the [tips for golfing in haskell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell)! (and I invite you to join [of monads and men](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men) :)

Comment: I spent some time trying to craft a fine solution utilizing xnor's tip... but I ended up with [this garbage](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0PDRstOU09DQ0dTD0gV56WAKDA/OlYvrbhEE8iFKtHWtFEBMeBSQHF0HUAuLh1Aqf@5iZl5CrYKBUWZeSUKKgppChqGOgpGmgoaxjoKJpr//yWn5SSmF//XTS4oAAA "Haskell – Try It Online"). I don't even know why I try sometimes...

Comment: @flawr What is the meta consensus on using external packages? The package I referenced isn't part of `base` so it would have to be installed.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo You are allowed to use packages.  If it's not in base its a different language, that's all.

Comment: If not for the import ban, I'd say `Biapplicative` was the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

## 44 bytes

Got this from `\x y -> (fst x + fst y, snd x + snd y)`

```hs
(<*>).((,).).(.fst).(+).fst<*>(.snd).(+).snd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYk5DoAgEAC/soXFriKJRym@xIagKBEJEd7virGaycyh07l5z1YtjFM9k0QUJAukTbmgoU/KQZnC@ocifGkXQEG8XchQgQXsRE@AgxiJH2O93hO3JsYX)

Or, 42 bytes using `do`:

```hs
do a<-fst;((,).(a+).fst<*>).(.snd).(+).snd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYg7DoAgDECv0sGhKJL42fycxKUBUSMiEc9v7fQ@O@VzDYH9tLC7gcba53dA1MogVcpIjeUsYXJ0AlkifNERYYL0HPGFAjxgo1sF2Ole8Wd9oC1zbVP6AQ)

Answer (score 9):

## 44 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen. -3 bytes thanks to Bruce Forte.*

```hs
(.).flip(.)<*>(zipWith(+).)$mapM id[fst,snd]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcU9DsIwDAbQq3xDBxtCJH5Gyg2YGYAhajG1SCOLZOrha3jLm1L9vHJ26R9OkaNktf/nzYUWtZu2ibYcuZuTXaHjXWoLtYxPn5MW9LCvloYOAtoHHBh0DDixr4Pk9K6@G8x@)

Translates to:

```hs
f t1 t2 = zipWith (+) (mapM id [fst, snd] $ t1) (mapM id [fst, snd] $ t2)
```

### 67 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen. -1 byte thanks to Bruce Forte.*

If tuple output is required:

```hs
(((,).head<*>last).).((.).flip(.)<*>(zipWith(+).)$mapM id[fst,snd])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYm7DsIwDAB/xUMHG0IkHiPlD5g7AIPVNMQijSycqR9PyHIn3SW2z5Jzi@OzIaIjnxYO190ts1Xy5BE7Yhbt7hk30Ulqwn2fw8p6BwmPaNVZCS9qK0uBEfQrpcIAEfDo4ESAZwcXar85Zn5bO8yqfw)

Yup, me manually doing it doesn't produce ripe fruit. But I am happy with the `[a] → (a, a)` conversion.

```hs
listToPair ∷ [a] → (a, a)
listToPair = (,) . head <*> last
-- listToPair [a, b] = (a, b)
```

Now if there was a *short* function with `m (a → b) → a → m b`.

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but `mapM id[fst,snd]` is shorter.

Comment: Sadly, `mapM id` is the *golfed* version of the function you're probably looking for, `sequence`.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'm just looking at `(<*>)`'s signature which is `m (a → b) → m a → m b`. So close...

Comment: There's also `Control.Lens.??`, which *may* have been proposed for inclusion in base at some point.

Comment: I want to extract the repeated `(.mapM id[fst,snd])` like `let r=(.mapM id[fst,snd]) in r(r.zipWith(+))`, but I haven't been able to get the typechecker to accept a pointfree version.

Comment: @xnor It's monotyped if you drop the `.`.

Answer (score 4):

## 60 bytes

I'm not seeing any `uncurry` love here, so I figured I'd pop in and fix that.

```
uncurry$(uncurry.).flip(.)(flip(.).(+)).(flip(.).((,).).(+))
```

I thought, with all of the `fst` and `snd`, that unpacking the arguments with `uncurry` might yield some results. Clearly, it was not as fruitful as I had hoped.

Comment: `uncurry` is so verbose. :( But you can replace the outermost parentheses with `$`.

Comment: Yeah, and that's unfortunately the issue with a lot of function names in Haskell. Just too long for golfing. But thanks for the 1-character savings!

Answer (score 4):

## 54 bytes

I honestly doubt that we'll beat @H.PWiz's 44 bytes solution, but nobody was using the fact that `(,)` implements the type class `Functor`, so here's another interesting one which isn't too bad:

```hs
((<*>snd).((,).).(.fst).(+).fst<*>).flip(fmap.(+).snd)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfpmCrEPNfQ8NGy644L0VTT0NDR1MPSOmlFZcAKW1NEAMoCaRzMgs00nITC8CiIMX/cxMz84D6C4oy80oUVBTSFDQMdXSNNBU0jHV0TTT//0tOy0lML/6vG@EcEAAA)

#### Explanation

The implementation of the type class `Functor` for *2*-Tuples are very similar to that of `Either` (from *base-4.10.1.0*):

```hs
instance Functor ((,) a) where
    fmap f (x,y) = (x, f y)

instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
    fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

What this means for this challenge, is that the following function adds the second elements while keeping the first element of the second argument:

```hs
λ f = fmap.(+).snd :: Num a => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)
λ f (1,-2) (3,-4)
(3,-6)
```

So if only we got some little helper `helpPlz = \a b -> (fst a+fst b,snd b)` we could do `(helpPlz<*>).flip(fmap.(+).snd)` and would be done. Luckily we have the tool [`pointfree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) which gives us:

```hs
helpPlz = (`ap` snd) . ((,) .) . (. fst) . (+) . fst
```

So by simply plugging that function back in we arrive at the above solution (note that `(<*>) = ap` which is in *base*).